# How to compare the video/image quality using protractor?

Tags: javascript, video, protractor

If you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz0PC.png) image, I'm trying to analyze Video1 with Video4 or Video2 with Video3

In a peer-to-peer WebRTC connection I'm trying to compare the video input of peer1 to the output on peer2. Basically I'm testing the quality of the video, and theoretically I can do that by :

- Checking the video itself frame by frame.
- Taking a screen shot on both the sides and checking the image resolution.

I've seen [this google video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbLNm3LsMaw&list=SPSIUOFhnxEiCODb8XQB-RUQ0RGNZ2yW7d) where they have mentioned a complex but clever idea of feeding a barcode stitched video and comparing the unique frame ID with each other. But, its written in C and ***I'm using protractor***

Is there anyone who have tried to do calculate an image resolution of an image or analyzing video frames? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The webrtc testing tool from [testrtc](https://github.com/webrtc/testrtc) has some code related to that. In particular the [cam resolution test](https://github.com/webrtc/testrtc/blob/master/src/js/camresolutionstest.js) which extracts the video from the canvas.

If you want to feed a special video stream from a file, that is doable with the [use-file-for-fake-video-capture](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-file-for-fake-video-capture) flag.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look and see if I can implement it in my project!

Comment: Apparently, running the webRTC tests on local computer via protractor doesn't seem to share webcam and mic. Spits out the following error on console:
`ERROR:stunport.cc(92). Binding request timed out...`

P.S. I can go around this issue by using two webcams, but it requires to manually change the default webcam on one of the peer window.